# PyQGIS script returning blank layer when applying singleband pseudocolor

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis

So I'm trying to automate applying singleband pseudocolor style using a python script on a height map (.tif file).

Here's the code :

```
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(inp, "pseudocolor_layer")
fcn = QgsColorRampShader()
fcn.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)
lst = [QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0, QColor(0,255,0)), QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(255, QColor(255,255,0)) ]
fcn.setColorRampItemList(lst)

# to make 5 classes
fcn.classifyColorRamp(5)
shader = QgsRasterShader()
shader.setRasterShaderFunction(fcn)
renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(rlayer.dataProvider(), 1, shader)
rlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
rlayer.triggerRepaint()
```

But I'm getting a blank layer. I ran these commands separately in the QGIS python console as well with no luck. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
fcn.classifyColorRamp(5)
```

QGIS doesn't seem to like this for some reason, you should submit a [new bug report issue](https://github.com/qgis/qgis/issues). The rest of your code looks fine.

---

**Edit:**

You could use something like the following to create 5 colour classes which can be seen in the raster legend (although for some reason, these are not reflected in the layers properties):

```
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(inp, "pseudocolor_layer")
fcn = QgsColorRampShader()
fcn.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)
fcn.setClassificationMode(QgsColorRampShader.Continuous)
lst = [QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0, QColor(255,0,0), 'First'), 
        QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(60, QColor(0,255,0), 'Second'),
        QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(120, QColor(0,120,0), 'Third'),
        QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(200, QColor(0,120,255), 'Fourth'),
        QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(255, QColor(0,0,255), 'Fifth') ]

fcn.setColorRampItemList(lst)
shader = QgsRasterShader()
shader.setRasterShaderFunction(fcn)
renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(rlayer.dataProvider(), 1, shader)
rlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
rlayer.triggerRepaint()
```

[image: raster]

Comment: What's the alternative then? Without that line of code I'm only getting two classes. Am I supposed to hardcode the classes?

Comment: @user56899 - Seems like a bug. I tried testing `classifyColorRamp()` on quantile mode but nothing happens and I can't seem to find any online examples using this method. I suggest you report this as mentioned in my post. I guess the alternative is to hardcode the 5 colour items.

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example of sorts? I can't quite figure out the ColorRampItem function parameters.

Comment: @user56899 - Edited post to show some code example. I'm also trying to grasp all the new functionality changes from the previous QGIS version :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: @user56899 - Most welcome! Hoped it helped :)

Comment: Issue remains. Has a bug report been submitted/resolved?